# I can't manage to get the TimePicker working in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an issue with the `<TimePicker>` / `<DatePicker>`.
I'm trying to make an "appointments" page, and I need the date and time.
For what I see, the DatePicker lets you chose the date (dd/mm/yyyy), but it returns a random time (12:00 AM).
I've tried to also get a TimePicker to work (So I can combine the two), but I can't manage to do it.

Right now I have:

```
<DatePicker MinimumDate="{Binding PropertyMinimumDate}" 
MaximumDate="12/12/2020" 
DateSelected="DatePicker_DateSelected" >
</DatePicker>

<TimePicker x:Name="TimeSelected" >
</TimePicker>
```

And

```
AppointmentLabel.Text = e.NewDate.Day.ToString() +"/"+ e.NewDate.Month.ToString() +"/"+ e.NewDate.Year.ToString() + " - "+TimeSelected.Time.ToString() +  "- Dr. Mark DavidS";
```

But it always returns 00:00.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to have a time selection screen in the DatePicker? Or am I not formating the time correctly? Or is there a way to get hold of the Time ,from the TimePicker, other than `x:Name`?

Comment: So your question is when you choose the time in TimerPicker and then choose date in DatePicker, at this point in the DataPicker DatePicker_DateSelected event you get TimePicker time is always 00.00?

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I was updateing the label in the datepicker event, so if I picked the date,then the time,the time wouldn't update.